# Avoid warning when implementing equals on class with generics

Tags: java, generics, suppress-warnings

I have the following code:

```
public abstract class A<T extends B<? extends A<T>>>{

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        A other = (A) obj; // warning here: "A is a raw type"
        // [...]
    }
}
```

How to avoid both "A is a raw type" and "Type safety: unchecked cast" at the specified line? Is there a hack of some sort or I am doing something wrong with my classes?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the parameterized type of the compared `A` doesn't matter, declare and cast it as `A<?>`:

```
A<?> other = (A<?>) obj;
```

This will remove the warning.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) This is gonna be my accepted answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Put this annotation before it: `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.  See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) for more info.

Comment: I know I can but all the beauty is avoiding to add it ;-p

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation as needed. See [here.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html)